# IBMXMSDotnetClient - Failed to create connection: AnalyseErrorSegment(MQTSH) entry [o] IBM.WMQ.MQTSH#024F4A7C

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, websphere, ibm-mq

Attempting to ensure/migrate that nuget .net standard2 of xms library works but after having issues with TLS & certificates it seems to be okay but I am now getting an error I cannot understand what it means.

```
12:48:39.989069  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket            ----+----+  <  ClientValidatingServerCertificate(Object,X509Certificate,X509Chain,SslPolicyErrors) rc=OK exit
12:48:39.989069  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket            ----+----  d  SSL Authentication completed

..

12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket            ----+----+-  <  Read(byte[], int, int) rc=OK exit
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  d  --------------------------
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  d  Receive Buffer

Length = 0x8000 (32768) bytes start=0 count=40

        offset        : 0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 A B  C D E F
0x00000000 (       0) : 54534820 00000028 02050a00 00000000 : TSH....(......
0x00000010 (      16) : 00000000 22020000 e4040000 0c000000 : ...."..?.....
0x00000020 (      32) : 18000000 3d000000                   : ...=...

12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  d  --------------------------
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  d  Data Length --> 40
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  <  Receive(ref byte [ ],ref int,ref int) rc=OK exit
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----  d  Bytes Read from Socket = 40
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+  >  ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) entry [o] System.Byte[], [o] 0
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+  <  ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) rc=OK exit [o] 28
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+  >  CheckTSH(byte [ ]) entry [o] System.Byte[]
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+  <  CheckTSH(byte [ ]) rc=OK exit [o] True
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  >  AnalyseErrorSegment(MQTSH) entry [o] IBM.WMQ.MQTSH#024F4A7C
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+-  >  GetLength() entry
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTSH                             ----+----+-  <  GetLength() rc=OK exit [o] 28
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQERD                             ----+----+-  >  ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) entry [o] System.Byte[], [o] 28
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQERD                             ----+----+-  <  ReadStruct(Byte [ ],int) rc=OK exit [o] 12
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001                                            ----+----+  d  New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001                                            ----+----+  d  New NmqiException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----+  <  AnalyseErrorSegment(MQTSH) rc=OK exit
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+----  <  ReceiveTSH(MQTSH) rc=OK exit
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+---  d  Exception in method InitialiseSession()
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+---  X  CompCode: 2, Reason: 2059
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+---  <  InitialiseSession() rc=OK exit
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+--  d  Exception in method Connect(MQConnectionSecurityParameters)
12:48:40.098529  8960.0001  IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection                   ----+--  X  CompCode: 2, Reason: 2059
```

Seems to be generic error but can someone interpret more details from it?
2059 - MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Edit:
Issue is due to cipher exchange for TLS/SSL - logs basically lie, managed code cannot force a cipher before .net 7
Not sure about the details of websphere as why not to limit in initial exchange of allowed cipher - maybe they don't know who you are but they could probably have solved it by creating a new ssl socket after initial exchange.

i.e. works with cipher set to "ANY" or similar style

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/sv/en/2023-2023-r1/Help/Content/UG/t_agents_websphere_MQ.htm

Comment: Which version of of Nuget package are you using? Have you check the Queue Manager error logs if they have some info on the error

Comment: latest: Version="9.3.3.1"
Asked for it, haven't setup any server.
Anything one can read from the trace? What this TSH &  AnalyseErrorSegment called form InitialiseSession

Comment: Also sad to loose the windows events that the unmanaged code produced - it was a more readable for troubleshooting even if not always super clear.

Comment: Can you try with 9.3.2/9.3.1? I think there is an APAR with 9.3.3

Comment: version: 9.3.2/9.3.1  -> same trace for both 
  
 & clarification same code/settings/properties but previous version was unmanged using version 9.1 & moved to managed and nuget dotnet standard (to simplify future migration to net6-8)

Comment: Did you use to have a private key in a kdb file that you used when connecting to the queue manager?

Comment: I had a .kdb file, spent some time to find that I could make a p12 file & set password from stashed file & then import it into certificate personal store

Comment: 15:08:37.545897  6236.0001  IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket            ----+----  d  CipherSpec value is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
...
15:08:37.702148  6236.0001  IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket            ----+----  d  SSL Authentication completed

Server side claims:
The channel will not run until this mismatch is
resolved. The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is
'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256'. The name of the CipherSpec negotiated during
the SSL handshake is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'.

Comment: a wild guess right now is that maybe the cipher is not supported as part of windows & managed code - so looks great but fails, think it is odd to fail it with 2059 thou & log that SSL is okay & working

Comment: cannot edit my comment, manage code cannot control cipher (.net 7 adds it) - so not possible, odd not throwing exception or warning log

i.e. modified server to allow "ANY" & it works